# format the encoded output of urllib quote_plus

Tags: python, urllib

I have a string list.

```
category_list = "[u'Automation', u' Card Readers &amp; POS']"
```

now, I'm performing below operation

```
category_list = urllib.quote_plus(category_list, safe=':/'.encode('utf-8'))
```

I post the encoded data to the network and while decoding the list the output format is like below.

```
[u\'Automation\', u\' Card Readers &amp; POS\']
```

This is the incorrect format for the API, I need to convert the list into below format (remove the \ ).

```
['Automation', ' Card Readers &amp; POS']
```

please help me regarding the same.

Comment: Explain why the source data is a string in the first place.

Comment: getting this error AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'rstrip' when tried encoding without string

Comment: Right but if you want to remove the `u` elements from the data then you need to convert it without those in the first place. So show where you are getting the data from and how you are converting it to a string.

Comment: I'm sending that data to a third party API. where I'm getting this error.

Comment: I didn't ask that. I asked you *where the data is from* and *how you're converting it to a string*.

Comment: `search_cat = request.GET['category'].split(',')   urllib.quote_plus(str(search_cat), safe=':/'.encode('utf-8'))`

Answer (score 0):

You're doing things the wrong way round. You get a string in `request.GET`, which your framework converts to unicode. By passing that directly to `str`, your unicode characters become part of that string; nothing that `quote_plus` can do would fix that. So, instead, you need to do the encoding before anything else.

```
search_cat = request.GET['category'].encode('utf-8').split(',')
urllib.quote_plus(str(search_cat), safe=':/')
```

Note though a much better solution would be for you to switch to Python 3, where all strings are unicode and the `u` prefix marker is not present.